# Expanding URLs in REST (flask) response

Tags: python, flask

I have developed a flask REST API using @miguelgrinberg course on developing REST apis. I am using the blueprint method (not flask-restful). When I return a collection (of resource URLS), my client has to make multiple calls to retrieve data. Is there an easy way for client to avoid making multiple calls.
For example:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        "http://localhost:7500/tasks-api/v1/tasks/id/1",
        "http://localhost:7500/tasks-api/v1/tasks/id/2"
    ],
    "pages": {
        "first_url": "http://localhost:7500/tasks-api/v1/tasks/?page=1&per_page=25",
        "last_url": "http://localhost:7500/tasks-api/v1/tasks/?page=1&per_page=25",
        "next_url": null,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 1,
        "per_page": 25,
        "prev_url": null,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

The question is how to (automatically) expand the nested resources without additional API calls.

Answer (score 0):

If there are different URLs, clearly you need to call them all. If some may be repetitions, as here, just  cache the result with a function that uses the  [a cache-with-timeout decorator](https://pypi.org/project/easy-cache/).

```
@ecached('geturl_{url}', 3600)
def get_with_cache(url):
    response: requests.Response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text
```